# Launch currently open script is not working in PHP Debug Adapter for Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am trying to debug a php cli script using vscode and the [php-debug extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug) So i added some breakpoints to the script and play `Launch currently open script` but the debug toolbar just show for a moment and hide.

This is the launch.json configuration

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

After configure the xdebug log I am getting this message

> Log opened at 2018-08-01 03:57:01 I: Connecting to configured
>   address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000. W: Creating socket for '127.0.0.1:9000',
>   poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29). E: Could not
>   connect to client. :-( Log closed at 2018-08-01 03:57:01

I read about this problem and it is recommended to change the port

Following the recommendations I change xdebug port in both `20-xdebug.ini` and `launch.json` file, but no success. I share the content of the files

/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

```
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9001
        }
    ]
}
```

After restarting apache and vscode in the log files I am getting this message

```
Log opened at 2018-08-01 04:07:01
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9001.
W: Creating socket for '127.0.0.1:9001', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2018-08-01 04:07:01
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: I am having a very similar issue. Did you figure out what was wrong?

Comment: No solution until now, In order to do the job I am using phpstorm, I followed this post instructions https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+PHP+CLI+scripts+with+PhpStorm to make it work

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.